# iOS locations updates with close app

Tags: ios, background, gps, location, multitasking

I am developing a child control app, so i need to send my current location to my server anytime when the child moves.

I know that exist significant location change and region monitoring that can wake up your app even if it is close, but when i try with this method i don't receive many updates and it has a bad accuracy because this services are base con cell tower changing.

How can i get periodically updates with a good accuracy (+-50m) when my app was not open by the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

You cannot!

significant location change and region monitoring are the only possibilities to wake up your app in relation to location change.
If the accuracy is not sufficient, then your idea will not work.

However you can get precise position in background mode.

Edit:
In ios7 You can also use [Beacon Regions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) (using bluetooth spots )

Comment: Can i wake up the app with region monitoring and significant location and then run in backgroud the standard location update?

Comment: Why not, but you have then to disable region monitoring to get acurate and frequent postions, then later at some time stop high quality psoitions, and reenable region monitoring. I have not tried that, but try it, if that makes sense to you.

Comment: I made that and works but when the app is close the accuracy is not the best. I have read that in iOS 7 the update service will change and my idea will work! So lets waits for the new iOS. Thanks @AlexWien